# Report generating from files in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vbscript

I would like to know how to generate a report based on the saved text files to my PC in a certain directory.

When i click report it will show me :

No. Of purchase orders : ( in a text box show value )

No. Of Purchase orders to (Site1 as a lab) : ( in a text box show value )

No. Of Purchase orders to (Site2 as a label) : ( in a text box show value )

No. Of Purchase orders to (Site3 as a label) : ( in a text box show value )

The (Site's) is from inside the text file each text file might contain different site.

Check out my form design and u might get an idea

My form design:

https://prnt.sc/itt1ts

one of my saved text file :

https://prnt.sc/itt1ts

And code for saving my file to path :

```
Select Case MsgBox("Do you wish to overwrite?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Save")
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine("D:\Logs", TextBox13.Text & ".txt")
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(filepath)
                sw.WriteLine(Label13.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label1.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox16.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label2.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label3.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label4.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox4.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label5.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox5.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label7.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox7.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label6.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox14.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label8.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox15.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label9.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox9.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label10.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox10.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label11.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox11.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(Label12.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox12.Text)
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("Over Written")
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select
```

In this case Text box (textbox2.text ) = Site

Need the saved sites from all documents to be check and give out a total number

Here is a rough sketch :

http://prntscr.com/iu4hoi

Comment: First your form design link is wrong, Second are you generating the reports yourself or are they coming from somewhere. If you are generating them yourself I would recommend using JSON or CSV which would make parsing so much easier. if you dont want then simply do something like: `Purchase Document *** 4200` in your text file. then you read each line and use a `string.split()`. I just saw you try to generate a Word report or a Text report?

Comment: Hi mederic i was trying to generate a text report

Comment: in Word format or Txt format

Comment: text format ofcaz

Comment: Mederic is it possible to give me ur skype ID or discord ID ?

Comment: sorry no please explain in details what your trying to achieve by editing your question